# Javascript scope issue - variable is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I am slightly confused by this, as i am sure that all variables are taken to the 'top' of the javascript before run time and then processed from there.

So my **error**

```
 TypeError: hutber.portfolio.ko is undefined
 [Break On This Error]  
 items: ko.observableArray(hutber.portfolio.ko.data),
```

**Object**

```
(function ($) {
"use strict"; //For good development standards :)
hutber.portfolio = {
    init: function(){
        e(typeof(hutber));
        hutber.portfolio.changeOptionsBoxHeight();
        //Bind the height resize in window resize
        $(window).resize(function(){
            hutber.portfolio.changeOptionsBoxHeight();
        });
        //start KO
        hutber.portfolio.ko.init();
    },
    changeOptionsBoxHeight: function(){
        var height = $(window).height();
        $('.portfolio--options').height(height-400);
    }
};
hutber.portfolio.ko = {
    init: function(){
        ko.applyBindings(new hutber.portfolio.ko.portfolioViewModel());
    },
    data: [],
    items: ko.observableArray(hutber.portfolio.ko.data),
    portfolioViewModel: function(){

        hutber.portfolio.ko.items = ko.observableArray(hutber.portfolio.ko.data);

        $.getJSON('/js/pages/portfolio.json').done(function(info){
            hutber.portfolio.ko.data = info;
            hutber.portfolio.ko.items (hutber.portfolio.ko.data);
        });
    }
};
hutber.portfolio.init();
})(jQuery);
```

I really wanted to upload this to a fiddle but for some reason, i'm getting js errors on their site. I believe my firewall is blocking certain files from loading.

Comment: I'm getting a _hutber is not defined_. You can use this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/welcome/73111/edit) instead of jsfiddle

Comment: @PabloGonzálezAlba: hutber has not been defined. But that is not the question.

Comment: cheer for that :) add hutber = {}; above (function ($) { to declare it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the point `ko.observableArray(hutber.portfolio.ko.data)` is run, `hutber.portfolio.ko` has not be defined yet.

You can work around it like that:

```
hutber.portfolio.ko = {
    init: function(){
        ko.applyBindings(new hutber.portfolio.ko.portfolioViewModel());
    },
    data: [],
    portfolioViewModel: function(){

        hutber.portfolio.ko.items = ko.observableArray(hutber.portfolio.ko.data);

        $.getJSON('/js/pages/portfolio.json').done(function(info){
            hutber.portfolio.ko.data = info;
            hutber.portfolio.ko.items (hutber.portfolio.ko.data);
        });
    }
};

hutber.portfolio.ko.items = ko.observableArray(hutber.portfolio.ko.data);
```

But at this point `hutber.portfolio.ko.data` is always `[]`. So you might as well put `ko.observableArray([])` in your original code.

Comment: does indeed fix the error, another one pops up. but thats really the point now is it :) I hadn't thought about adding to the object on the fly like that. Not sure why i was so dead set on making sure it was defined in the objects chain as it were.

Comment: Also `hutber.portfolio.ko.items (hutber.portfolio.ko.data);` this row might throw an error as long as `ko.observableArray()` does not return a function. But I do not know that much about Knockout.

Comment: ye, i also thought that it had to be a function. Enough hunting round turns out it doesn't need to be a function. Just an object, array etc etc

Answer (score 0):

Just guess: Because you accessing variable before you declare it?

Comment: pretty sure i have declared it. :/